# P/Invoke Interop Assistant - Is it as easy as importing the dll's headers?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, interop, pinvoke

I am trying to create wrappers for a set of unmanaged C++ libraries. I have the code for the libraries so I downloaded the P/invoke interop assistant.

I am a little confused as to what the exports are in the C++ projects. Is it just the headers for the project?

It is quite a large project. Do I just load the headers from each library into the command line tool and generate the C# signatures?

After this is done do I need to manually add the actual dll import to them after as shown below, or is there a way to define  it as one DLL?:

```
[DllImport(MyDLL.dll)]
```

Comment: For your second question: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/01/12/p-invoke-signature-generator.aspx

Comment: Would be very surprising if the interop assistant could do it all for you. Expect to write much of this yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Pinvoke Interop Assistant uses so-called SAL annotations in the Windows header files to get more accurate pinvoke declarations.  SAL helps tooling to analyze code better, C and C++ declarations are not usually good enough to determine whether a pointer refers to a single value or an array of values and doesn't specify the flow of the data, whether it is consumed by the function or returned by it.  Things that matter a great deal when you write a [DllImport] attribute.  SAL adds that missing information.

It is pretty unlikely that your C++ code has these SAL annotations.  Look for markup in the C++ declarations that look like `__in`, `__in_opt`, `__deref_out`, written before the arguments of a function.  Without this markup, the Pinvoke Interop Assistant is incapable of doing a better job.

An additional hang-up is that pinvoke doesn't support true C++ declarations, it is only suitable for C declarations.  In other words, you cannot pinvoke an instance method of a C++ class or deal with a C++ function accepting or returning a C++ object, like std::string etc.  You must write a managed wrapper in the C++/CLI language instead.

SWIG is an open source tool that tries to make this kind of job easier.  It does suffer from the classic "now you've got two problems" scenario, to deal with the difficult cases you really do have to learn two things, pinvoke as well as SWIG.

A good resource for finding the proper [DllImport] declaration is the one you already found, you can ask a question about it here.  Be sure to post the exact C++ declaration and a short description of what the function does.

Comment: I just downloaded SWIG, and I guess I am still a little confused. I am unsure how to actually use it to generate the initial wrappers. In the documentation it only states that their is sample projects in the folder for C#. From what I understand I somehow need to attach SWIG to the C++ project, but I can't understand how to do so. I only need to attach it t so I can generate the initial C# code-or figure out how to do it otherwise, from there I will manually fix it. Do you think you can help me out?

Comment: Yes, that's the "now you have two problems" scenario I warned you about.  No, I can't help you, I never liked having two problems and never needed SWIG.